# How to change images repeatedly for a specific time

Tags: android

I want to implement a flash type layout, with repeat changes of images in my application.
i have a banner , should be change to banner2 in 5 seconds of time. is this possible todo?
can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Need some more info: Is it like a animated intro? Or like a slide show?

Comment: Yes Exactly, its like a flash image transition, automatic slide show. Can you help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into AnimationDrawables, which enable you to create the type of animation you require.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was implemented the animationDrawable example. But there is no sliding effect for image to image,  one image is staying completely for overall the app. do i need to do any changes ?